# High Charts Exporting on IOS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am facing High charts issue on ipad only, I have two charts added in a single page, when i click download image of one chart it never opens export menu of other chart, which is correct but when i click download image of chart then it opens the export menu of that chart without closing the previous one. This behavior is working fine on desktop. Working fine on Chrome ipad view. Only issue on ipad, only one export menu should be opened at a time. Attached is the image for more details. current version of high charts i am using is 5.0.7. Please share your thoughts on this issue. Moreover, if I close one of the export menu both menus of both charts are getting closed at one's.[image]

Comment: Can you share the code which causes the issue? You can recreate the problem live, e.g. on sjfiddle.

Comment: @morganfree There is no custom code written for this implementation, high charts api's are being used for this.

Comment: I checked this code http://jsfiddle.net/o1frvt29/ on iPad on Safari and the exporting menus seem to work correctly. You can adjust the fiddle and provide me with the details how to reproduce the problem.